# How can i filter songs using persistent id

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipod, mpmediaquery

ì have an iPhone application in which i should filter the songs by genre or album, filter the albums by artist etc. But i have a doubt about how to filter items. I read in apple's documentation that for example to get songs for a specific album you should make a MPMediaPropertyPredicate in which you specify the album name as the value of the predicate and  MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle as property. But in their documentation they say that we can filter items using also the persistent id of an album for example.
Could someone please give me an example in which i could load the songs of a specific album using the persistent of the album.
Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

An album doesn't have a persistent id. The iPod library only has track objects basically - it's not a relational database with artist, albums and track records.

If you want to load all songs from an album, you simply search on album/albumartist texts.